# Programmatically Control ListView CSS

Tags: asp.net, css, listview

I have two ListViews in an E-Commerce store, one for the products and one for the cart. I'm adding products for the cart with a LinkButton CommandName in the products ListView. Each time I add a product (row) to the cart I'm getting a double border between the rows.

So I have set the CSS for the top, left and right borders only, in my CSS style sheet. What I want to do is add the bottom border programmatically in the code-behind. Do I do this in the ItemCreated handler and what syntax would I use?

Comment: Why do you want to add the bottom border dynamically instead of using a [`:last-child`](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/firstchild.html) selector and adding a bottom border that way?

Comment: Not reliable across all browsers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your border-bottom via your existing class, then add a new class to RowIndex 0 and set your border-top property for the new class.

In the ItemTemplate:

```
    <tr class='<%# (Container.DataItemIndex == 0 ? " ClassName" : null) %>'>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's probably easier to tell when you're on the first element and add a top bar than tell when you're on the last element and add a bottom bar.  You could put a private class variable starts out set to `True`.  Then in your [ItemDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.itemdatabound.aspx) event, if the variable is true, add a `first` or something class to the element and set the variable to `False` so every other element will skip over the code.